# Certificate not found AWS Client Endpoint, when generating from ACM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-certificate-manager

EDIT: I need to request certificates, after generating CAs, as per [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request-private.html#request-private-console) link. I wrongly assumed the certificate attached to the CA was the desired certificate for use within the VPN Client Endpoint wizard.

Instructions are as follows:

> Sign into the AWS Management Console and open the ACM console at
> https://console.aws.amazon.com/acm/home
>
> Choose Request a certificate.
>
> On the Request a certificate page, choose Request a private
> certificate and Request a certificate to continue.
>
> On the Select a certificate authority (CA) page, click the Select a CA
> field to view the list of available private CAs identified by ARN. If
> the CA is shared from another account, the ARN is prefaced by
> ownership information. Choose a CA from the list.
>
> Details about the CA are displayed to help you verify that you have
> chosen the correct CA:

---

I am trying to use the certificates that I generated in ACM with the VPN Client Endpoint service. I have generated a root ca, then a server and client ca as subordinate to that root ca, in the ACM.

[image: certificates list]

When I go to use these in the Client VPN Endpoint generation wizard, it does not appear available.

[image: client endpoint generator]

If I attempt to just copy paste the ARN as found on the "Status" tab of the certificate, when generating the client vpn endpoint I receive an error:

[image: "Certificate not found"]

Comment: You need to upload your certs to the certificate manager. Based on your screenshot, it looks like you uploaded them to the ACM private CA instead.

Comment: Oh I see! Of course... how silly. Thanks! Also I found instructions, will link in edit.